# Remove/Hide Text at Footer of Contact Form

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm using Wordpress and FormGet. When I paste the HTML code of the contact from of FormGet into a page on my site (http://jrbweddings.com/contact/) it adds a "Report Abuse' text at the bottom of the form. Is there a way to remove this or make the text white? It has an 'a' tag and if I try to use css code it changes the whole site.

Here is the code for the form:

```
<iframe style="width: 100%; border: none;" src="//www.formget.com/app/forms/view/FELr-104915/i?w=328" width="300" height="1257" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">Your Contact </iframe>
```

Comment: Please don't make text white, it's the most awful bad practice and could cause you problems with search engines hiding text, especially links by making them invisible against the background.

Comment: Nope, it's an iframe. Not much you can do about it, unless you're able to change the parameters via the iframe itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the HTML and CSS for the page inside the `<iframe>` are out of your control.

If so (and alternative inline contact plugins are out of the question), I can only suggest you use the `<iframe>` parameters to "cut off" the lower part of the frame's content with a smaller height:

`<iframe style="width: 100%; border: none;" src="//www.formget.com/app/forms/view/FELr-104915/i?w=328" width="300" height="990" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">Your Contact </iframe>`

Comment: Thanks for the help. The only thing is if you choose an item in the 'I'm interested in...' drop-down, it slides the form down and part of it gets cut off. Is there a way to increase the footer padding of the 'Report Abuse' text and then shorten the height?

Comment: In which case, you would be better off following @i-CONICA and installing something you can actually take visual control of. I recommend Contact Form 7; a very flexible and extensible Wordpress contact form plugin.

Comment: I understand, but I want to try this form for the moment. My last question is, am I able to add a margin to the bottom of the form through css?

Comment: You'd only really be able to apply a margin to the iframe itself with `style="margin-bottom:30px;"`

Comment: Ok. How would I add that in with the iframe? I'm not the best with code

Comment: That goes in the style attribute: `<iframe style="margin-bottom: 30px; width: 100%; border: none;" src="//www.formget.com/app/forms/view/FELr-104915/i?w=328" width="300" height="1257" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">Your Contact </iframe>`

Answer (score 0):

The contents are loaded from an iframe. You can't bind to any elements inside the iframe using javascript, or using CSS for that matter, unless you have access to the web page that's being loaded, which you don't.

As you've already got a great CMS, you don't need to be loading in forms from 3rd parties like this. Install a contact form plugin. There's no coding to be done, it's all very simple now. Search for one, select by highly rated, and install it, you can then customise it in it's menu.